# Asterisk - сохранение набранного номера телефона в переменную

Tags: asterisk

У меня должен совершаться набор номера телефона через софтфон, после чего должен совершаться звонок на внешний номер ${OUTGOING}, после поднятия трубки - совершаться звонок с номера ${OUTGOING} на номер, который мы набрали в софтфоне. Своего рода такой редирект.

Я смог в [globals] определить глобальную переменную ${OUTGOING} и передать в неё свой номер телефона, но я понятия не имею, как сохранить набранный номер телефона, когда мы звоним с софтфона (MicroSip в моём случае)

Для примера здесь я звоню на 1003(внутренний номер), после чего совершается звонок на мой номер ${OUTGOING} и дальше с моего номера на забитый в ручную номер

```
[outcoling]
exten => 1003,1,Goto(transfer,gogo,1)
exten => _XXXX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN},,m)
exten => _7XXXXXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/sunsim/${EXTEN})
exten => _+7XXXXXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/sunsim/${EXTEN})
exten => _8XXXXXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/sunsim/${EXTEN})

[transfer]
exten => gogo,1,Answer
exten => gogo,n,System(asterisk -rx "originate Local/${OUTGOING}@outcoling/n extension 
+7******5923@outcoling")
exten => gogo,n,Hangup
```